# Monodevelop - Ubuntu - exe file as output?

Tags: ubuntu, binary, monodevelop

OK I'm creating an app in MonoDevelop for Ubuntu Linux, but the compiled file is always a windows exe, I've set it to compile as a Linux Binary but I'm confused, can anyone shed any light on how to get a proper Linux way of opening the program?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It compiles to be a .NET executable assembly - these are always `.exe` files.

You can run it in linux by calling the mono runtime:

```
mono myExe.exe
```

Comment: Will the mono runtime be available on all linux distros though? And finally how would I execute this program without the terminal showing? Thanks.

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal - No, only on systems that have it installed. I believe the ubuntu family have it installed by default, but you can't rely on that.